# Statistical independence of $\operatorname{sign}(x)$ and $\lvert x \rvert$

Tags: statistics, independence

suppose X is a normal random variable with zero mean and the variance is equal to squared sigma (X ~ N(0,$\sigma^2$)), I want to prove that 
$\operatorname{sign}(x)$ and $\lvert x \rvert$ are statistically independent.

I've been trying to prove it and to find a proof on the web but with no success.
Can anyone help me with a proof?

Answer (score 2):

Independence means that knowing one gives you no information about the distribution of the other.

Intuitively, if you know the sign of a $N(0,\sigma^2)$ (or any symmetric) random variable, it tells you nothing of its magnitude since the distribution of magnitudes of the positive half of the distribution is identical to that of the negative half.

Think about it the other way too. You could generate a normal variable by first drawing the magnitude from whatever its distribution is and then flipping an coin (independent of the magnitude) for the sign. This works because of the symmetry. Conditional on the magnitude being, say $1.2,$ the RV is $\pm 1.2$ with equal probability. So the sign is $\pm 1$ with equal probability.

Formally, you need to show for any $x$ $$ P(|X| < x , \mathrm{sign}(X) = +1) = P(|X|<x)P(\mathrm{sign}(X) = +1),$$ and similarly for $-1.$ The intuition from the paragraphs above should help.